# mongo aggregation - number of documents where field in one array is also in another one

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have a Movies collection

```
...
{
    ...
    "cast":[ "First Actor", "Second Actor" ],
    "directors":[ "First Director", "Second Director" ]
},
{
    ...
    "cast": [ "Actor Director", "First Actor" ],
    "directors": [ "Actor Director", "Firt Director" ]
}
...
```

Using aggregation framework I need to get number of documents where at least one value from **directors** array is also in a **cast** array. How could I achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by aggregation framework? Are you using a specific library?

Comment: I mean aggregation pipeline
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) to find common entries in both arrays, then filter documents by [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the result gt than 0 (means that at least one element is common to arrays), and finally use [$count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/)  stage to count documents that match this condition.

-- EDIT : Add $addFields stage in case of no array present for cast or directors

In case of any document that doesn't contain cast or directors array, you will get an error for size waiting for an array and getting a null value.
In order to avoid this, you need to add an $addField stage to define empty array instead of null, for cast and directors.

Here's the query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      directors: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $isArray: "$directors"
          },
          then: "$directors",
          else: []
        }
      },
      cast: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $isArray: "$cast"
          },
          then: "$cast",
          else: []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: {
              $setIntersection: [
                "$cast",
                "$directors"
              ]
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $count: "have_common_value"
  }
])
```

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eeNIKtvPJuV)

Comment: It throws an error: "errmsg" : "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: null"

Comment: You probably have documents where cast and/or directors array is missing. I edited my answer to take care of that, and playground

Comment: it works! Thank you very much sir. I really appreciate your help.